# Is it possible to change a web2py view on the fly?

Tags: view, web2py

Can you change the view being used by web2py in the controller? Ideally I'd be interested in doing something like:

response.view = 'NewViewName'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got it exactly, though be sure to include the relative path to the view within the /views folder. So, if you have /views/default/other_view.html, you can do:

```
response.view = 'default/other_view.html'
```

You can also directly render any view:

```
def myfunc():
    context = dict(...)
    return response.render('default/other_view.html', context)
```

See [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/4?search=response.view) and [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/4?search=response.render).